# Trying to match RegEx to text returned by promise -- getting empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, promise, pdf.js

I'm using PDF.js to get text from a PDF, which I then parse with a RegEx. The `parsetext` function takes a `text` argument that is returned by a promise:

```
 gettext: function(url){
     var self = this;
     var data = url;
     console.log('attempting to get text');
     return pdfjs.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {
         var pages = [];
         for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
             pages.push(i);
         }
         return Promise.all(pages.map(function(pageNumber) {
             return pdf.getPage(pageNumber + 1).then(function(page) {
                 return page.getTextContent().then(function(textContent) {
                     return textContent.items.map(function(item) {
                         return item.str;
                     }).join(' ');
                 });
             });
         })).then(function(pages) {
             return pages.join("\r\n")
         });
     }).then(function(pages){
         self.parsetext(pages);      
     });        
 },

 parsetext: function(text){

     var rx = /Seite((\S+)\s+\S.*?)(?=\s*\2)/;
     var s = text;
     var m = s.match(rx) || ["", ""];
     console.log(m[1] + ' is the matched text');  //   returns '  is the matched text'
 }
```

`m[1]` should be returning a lengthy string.

removed confused case involving trying to get captured groups from String.match() when no captured groups were used -- the main problem remains unsolved, so this is no duplicate.

Where could the problem be originating? The RegEx seems fine, so I can only imagine this is a result of `gettext` not returning the full string before `parsetext` is run. But isn't that what the promise ensures?

I don't think this is a problem with there being no return value, as the penultimate promise is returning a string. To prove this, I added a console.log to show what is being returned:

```
 gettext: function(url){
     var self = this;
     var data = url;
     console.log('attempting to get text');
     return pdfjs.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {
         var pages = [];
         for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
             pages.push(i);
         }
         return Promise.all(pages.map(function(pageNumber) {
             return pdf.getPage(pageNumber + 1).then(function(page) {
                 return page.getTextContent().then(function(textContent) {
                     return textContent.items.map(function(item) {
                         return item.str;
                     }).join(' ');
                 });
             });
         })).then(function(pages) {
             return pages.join("\r\n")
         });
     }).then(function(pages){
         self.parsetext(pages);      
     });        
 },
 parsetext: function(text){
     console.log(text + ' is the text that is being returned from the promise');
     var rx = /Seite((\S+)\s+\S.*?)(?=\s*\2)/;
     var s =  text;
     var m = s.match(rx) || ["", ""];
     console.log(m[0] + ' is the matched text');
 }
```

This logs:

```
'...SeiteSGP0136.1 3SE7120 3SE7120-1BF00 SGP0137.1 3SE7140 3SE7140-1CD00 SGP0138.1 3SE7150 3SE7150-1BH00 SGP0136.1 is the text that is being returned from the promise'
```

Just to show that the RegEx isn't broken:

https://jsfiddle.net/dqewqwvk/5/

Comment: @JaromandaX   doesn't .`then(function(pages) {
         return pages.join("\r\n")
     });` return text, which is then sent to `self.parsetext`?

Comment: When tou try to hardcode things, you're using a regexp that doesn't group anything. The regexp matches successfully, but since the result contains **only** the full match you're getting `undefined` from `m[1]`, since `m` only has a single item

Comment: @MikaelLennholm  Why isn't m[1] undefined here https://jsfiddle.net/dqewqwvk/5/?

Comment: @DavidJ., because you have a capture group in that regular expression (i.e. parentheses): `((\S+)\s+\S.*?)`. The part that is captured by that sub expression gets stored in `m[1]`. In that case there is also `m[2]` which corresponds to what the nested group `(\S+)` matches.

Comment: @trincot  Ahh, I see - thank you

Comment: @trincot  Edited question to show how this is not a duplicate -- the capture group was a coincidental misunderstanding -- this appears to be a problem with promises

Comment: See the very first comment made by Jaromanda X: you don't return a promised value in the final `then` callback, so the promised value will be `undefined`.

Comment: @trincot  Regardless, you marked it as an exact duplicate of a question with a completely different problem -- i.e. a capture group not being present.

Comment: I marked it with that duplicate because you had mentioned that as a problem in your question. Now that your question is focusing on a problem with the return value, I have linked to another duplicate that deals with that.

Comment: @trincot  I still don't think this is a duplicate.  If nothing is being returned by the promise, why is the new `console.log` I added logging the text from `gettext`?

Comment: In your "edit 2" you are not calling `gettext` at all.

Comment: @trincot  I only included the relevant part --- edit 2 is the exact same as the original text with an additional console.log.  (If it didn't include gettext's return value then text would be undefined...).  I'll edit it again to show if this isn't obvious.

Comment: Where do you call `gettext`? You wrote *"The regex seems fine, so I can only imagine this is a result of `gettext` not returning the full string before `parsetext` is run."* --- You imagine that right, but you never have shown the code where you call `gettext`, which *will* return a promise resolving to `undefined`.

Comment: @trincot  If I weren't calling `gettext`, then `parsetext` wouldn't be evaluating, and no messages would be logging to the console.  Of course `gettext` is being called.

Comment: @trincot   I agree, gettext will return undefined.  But parsetext is not using the return value of gettext as its argument.  It's just using the return value of the penultimate promise of gettext.  And IF that were actually undefined, it wouldn't be logging to the console, as I showed in edit 2.

Comment: @trincot  I am not claiming that parsetext is using the return value of gettext.  See my previous comment - "I agree, gettext will return undefined. But parsetext is not using the return value of gettext as its argument."

Comment: @trincot  It's very simple to see the argument that parsetext is being called with -- it's the text that is outputed with the first console.log in edit 2.

Comment: @trincot: may I suggest you drop this? The question isn't an issue of async programming. The OP even logged / explained that the text is getting into the `parsetext` function.

Comment: I rest my case, and will follow this silently.

Comment: @JaromandaX  Maybe it's not the clearest way to use promises, but I am calling parsetext with the return value of the second to last promise from gettext.  This doesn't return undefined, and should theoretically give me the text to work with for my regex -- which is mysteriously not matching correctly.

Comment: Indeed that is mysterious - so you only ever get `'  is the matched text'`

Comment: @JaromandaX  Exactly

Comment: PDF might contain other control chars, please use `JSON.stringify(text)` to log stuff

Comment: @async5  Thanks for the hint, this helped me solve the problem.  Apparently the text being returned had added spaces following `Seite` that weren't showing up in the basic `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @async5 's suggestion I was able to solve this by first noticing that the text being matched against the regex wasn't what I thought it was

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(text));  //   '...Seite                     SGP0136.1...'
```

which showed me that there were extra spaces inserted following `Seite`, which was breaking my regex.

My solution was to replace sequences of more than three spaces with the empty string:

```
     var rx = /Seite((\S+)\s+\S.*?)(?=\s*\2)/;
     var s =  text.replace(/\s{3}\s+/g, '');
     var m = s.match(rx) || ["", ""];
     console.log(m[1] + ' is the matched text');
```